# least square regression model

Tags: r, regression, least-squares

What is behind Approx and approxfun? I know that these two functions perform a linear interpolation, however I didn't find any reference on how they do that. I guess they use a least square regression model but I am not sure.

Finally, if it's true that they use a least square regression model what is the difference between them and lm + predict?

Comment: Read the [source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/fbf5cdf29d923395b537a9893f46af1aa75e38f3/src/library/stats/src/approx.c).

Comment: I think it does the least square regression  right?

Comment: Wrong. It just draws straight lines between points.

Answer (score 1):

As commented , you should read the source code.  Interpolation problem

> Find y(v),  given (x,y)[i], i = 0,..,n-1 */

For example `approxfun` use a simple this algorithm for linear approximation :

1. y(v),  given (x,y)[i], i = 0,..,n-1 */
2. find the correct interval (i,j) by bisection */
3. Use i,j for linear interpolation

Here an R code that aprahrase the C function approx1 :

```
approx1 <- 
  function( v, x, y)
{
  ## Approximate  y(v),  given (x,y)[i], i = 0,..,n-1 */


  i <- 1
  j <- length(x) 
  ij <- 0

  ## find the correct interval by bisection */
    while(i < (j-1) ) { 
         ij <- floor((i + j)/2)
         if(v < x[ij]) 
             j <- ij 
         else 
           i <- ij
    }
  ## linear interpolation */

    if(v == x[j]) return(y[j])
    if(v == x[i]) return(y[i])

    return (y[i] + (y[j] - y[i]) * ((v - x[i])/(x[j] - x[i])))
  }
```